# Workforce for ArcGIS - Can't create Project

Tags: create, workforce

I'm new to Workforce. I can't seem to be able to create a project in Workforce. Any time I try to create a new project, the error below pops up:

"Unable to create project.
SSL Required SSL Required"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your organization settings, are you forcing traffic through HTTPS?[image]

Workforce now supports access through HTTPS. If your organization only allows access through HTTPS, you need to access Workforce through https://workforce.arcgis.com.

Comment: if the answer worked please mark as correct so we can close this.